# Getting Error Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server

when I am executing this stored procedure, I get an error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Code:

```
alter procedure AutoUpdate_EmpSal
as
begin
DECLARE @cmd AS NVARCHAR(max)
CREATE TABLE #result 
        (           
           SalaryId          int,
           EmpId             INT,           
           TakenSalary       float,
           AvailSalary       float
        )       
declare @salaryId   int
declare @empId  int
declare @takenSalary float
declare @availSalary float

SET @cmd ='select * from Employee_SalaryDetails where SalaryId in( SELECT max(SalaryId) FROM Employee_SalaryDetails group by EmpId )'
Insert into #result 
         EXEC(@cmd)

declare result_cursor cursor for 
    select SalaryId,EmpId,TakenSalary,AvailSalary
    from  #result

OPEN result_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM result_cursor INTO @salaryId,@empId,@takenSalary,@availSalary

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0                                          
BEGIN   
    update Employee_SalaryDetails 
    set Employee_SalaryDetails.AvailSalary=(@availSalary+Employee.Salary)
    from Employee_SalaryDetails,Employee
    where Employee_SalaryDetails.SalaryId=@salaryId 
    and Employee_SalaryDetails.EmpId=Employee.EmpId
FETCH NEXT FROM result_cursor INTO @salaryId,@empId,@takenSalary,@availSalary
end
select * from #result
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the '*' from your cmd query and select those columns which have in #result table as it is..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can select detail columns to insert. You can change this code:

```
select * from Employee_SalaryDetails
where SalaryId in( SELECT max(SalaryId) FROM Employee_SalaryDetails group by EmpId)
```

to code:

```
select SalaryId, EmpId, TakenSalary, AvailSalary FROM Employee_SalaryDetails
where SalaryId in( SELECT max(SalaryId) FROM Employee_SalaryDetails group by EmpId)
```